# CSRF using AJAX. Why is it possible?

Tags: ajax, security, csrf, same-origin-policy, websecurity

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/
2. Open developer console in your web browser
3. Execute the following JS code:

   ```
   fetch(`https://webhook.site/5a6f8001-3646-4b3e-bd76-a4562af5a9ef`, { credentials: 'include' })
   ```
4. Go to https://webhook.site/#!/5a6f8001-3646-4b3e-bd76-a4562af5a9ef

You should see the HTTP request on https://webhook.site

Why does the HTTP request reach the server?
Does this violate Same Origin Policy?

Comment: Do you mean CORS instead of CSRF? CSRF is more a protection for when cookies are being used as an authentication mechanism. If you indeed meant CORS, I guess `webhook.site` simply allows any origin? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @sp00m No, I mean CSRF attack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: I do have CORS blocking my request when I try your snippet FYI, origin `https://stackoverflow.com` not allowed.

Comment: @sp00m and now check this https://webhook.site/#!/5a6f8001-3646-4b3e-bd76-a4562af5a9ef . Do you see your request?

Comment: Hmm, not too sure I understand how that site works actually...

Comment: https://webhook.site/ just logs HTTP requests

Comment: Interesting, although the request is cancelled by the browser because of CORS, it does seem that the request reach the server indeed. I'd have expected the request to not even reach the server. Surprising, I'll wait for smarter brains to reach this question :)

Comment: If this is perceived (As I understand it) as a vulerability specifically for this website, maybe this should be put on [the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @Martin no, this should work on any site without CSP

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not mix SOP, CORS and CSRF.

1. SOP (same-origin policy) checks are performed by **the browser** and help to **protect** resource in your origin that access from **"other" origins**. If they needed to be allowed permission to they could **read** your contents, you need to define rules to extend to restrictions called **CORS**.
2. CSRF (cross-site request forgery) is an attack that is helping to create or send a malicious invalidated request via the victim's cookie. Every request after reach to target origin with the victim's cookie that will be executed via that user's permission. So, The attacker does not read the response. Also, you cannot read responses because of **Same Origin Policy** rules unless they do not allow read to their content with **CORS rules**.